# How to maintain a connection session with sendSynchronousRequest

Tags: iphone, ios, session, nsurlconnection, synchronous

Here is my connection code:

```
- (void)sendData: (NSString*)someData {    
 NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:nsURL]
                                                        cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                    timeoutInterval:180.0];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setTimeoutInterval:180.0];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:[sdata dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

NSError *error= nil;
NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
}
```

I am calling this method whenever I have to send some request to the user. However, I want to maintain a specific connection session, and send requests, without creating the connection again and again. (as, the URL is a secure connection, and everytime it creates a connection, it wastes a lot of time).

How can I do this? Is there any way of creating a global object for connection in this class(where sendData method is written), so that for the lifetime of that object, there is only one connection.?

Comment: Are you really intending to keep a connection open (which wont work due to cellphone operator limitations -> see SocketIO's workaround, aka long-polling) or do you want to keep a login session?

Comment: I am trying to keep a connection open, as it is a series of request<-->response that I have to do. If I create a connection every time, the whole process becomes very slow.

Comment: @NikitaP Were any of the answers helpful or is the issue still open?

Comment: @TommieC. Well, there is no specific answer to what I wanted to be done. So, the issue is still open and not.

There is only one way to keep the connections open, and that is to create an asynchronous request in `didFinishLoading` and use that entirely

Answer (score 0):

Cellular provider restrictions aside, the choice to keep a connection open is up to the server, not the client. If this is a request over HTTPS, you want to look at your server documentation regarding keep-alive connections and increase the timeout to a value that makes sense for your app.

The URL loading system will automatically re-use a connection to the same server, provided that it has not been closed by the server.

Note that increasing the keep-alive timeout on your server to a large value will mean a potentially significant increase of the resources used by the server.